# how to combine the results of apply iteratively

Tags: r

I wanted to multiply to each list element in  say l1 with b1's col1 and store it in a separate column. Basically this is what i wanted to do :

```
res = 0 
for item in a 
  for col_item in b
    res = res + item * col_item
```

E.g.

```
l1 = list(c('17-Nov-14', 10), c('17-Apr-15', 20))
b1 = data.frame(col1 = c(10, 20), res=c(0))
result = data.frame(col1= c(10, 20), res = c(2*10+4*10+3*10, 2*20+4*20+3*20))
```

I have a working code but can be improved.

```
test <- function(param, df) {
    df$res <- as.integer(param[2]) * df$col1
    df
}

t <- lapply(l1, test, b)
result <- cbind(t[[1]]$col1, t[[1]]$res + t[[2]]$res + t[[3]]$res)
```

Comment: `b1$res <- sum(unlist(l1)) * b1$col1`?

Comment: I cannot do sum(unlist(l1)). It has to process each elements of l1 seperately.

Comment: It doesn't seem so according to your logic unless your real case is different from what you are posting.

Comment: In the original problem the list l1 has multiple columns, so sum(unlist(l1) will not help. The test function has multiple conditions. I think one way to solve is if I can save the result of each iteration and pass it to next iteration. This can be easily done when a for loop is used using a temporary variable. Not sure how it can be done when you use apply functions. Sorry for not mentioning the problem clearly in the  first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>We can simplify the computation with a little algebra. If we factor out the element of `b1$col1`, then we can precompute the sum of the list and perform a vectorized multiplication against it:</s>

```
b1$res <- sum(unlist(l1))*b1$col1;
b1;
##   col1 res
## 1   10  90
## 2   20 180
```

For your new problem definition, we need to extract the required element out of each list component vector:

```
b1$res <- sum(as.integer(sapply(l1,`[`,2L)))*b1$col1;
b1;
##   col1 res
## 1   10 300
## 2   20 600
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a method to reduce your list after `lapply`, you can use the `Reduce` function:

```
Reduce(function(df1, df2) data.frame(col = df1[1], res = df1[2] + df2[2]), myList)
#   col1 res
# 1   10  90
# 2   20 180
```

Suppose `myList <- lapply(...)`.